# value of text box and div text isn't updating properly after using datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I've got an issue where im using jQuery UI's Datepicker to populate a couple of fields with the date that has been set.

Basically what i am trying to do is after a date has been chosen, update a text field to display that date's day (This is working as it should be, i believe anyway) and then to also update a div with the day chosen too (This is just for testing purposes, i have a lot more to do in future but can't do that until i get this bit sorted). Butfor some reason it won't update automatically. Do i need to put it inside a click function to refresh the data?

heres the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="widgetContainer">Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="selected_day" size="30" value="" />
    <br />
    <select name="times">
        <option value="12pm" selected="selected">12pm</option>
        <option value="1pm">1pm</option>
        <option value="2pm">2pm</option>
        <option value="3pm">3pm</option>
        <option value="4pm">4pm</option>
        <option value="5pm">5pm</option>
        <option value="6pm">6pm</option>
        <option value="7pm">7pm</option>
        <option value="8pm">8pm</option>
        <option value="9pm">9pm</option>
        <option value="10pm">10pm</option>
        <option value="11pm">11pm</option>
    </select>
    <div id="result">Result:</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            altField: "#selected_day",
            altFormat: "DD"
        });
        $('#selected_day').change(function () {
            var day = this.val();
            $('#result').text('Result:' + day);
        });
    });
});
```

and a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/c3u5B/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHen you update a value of input with script , change event is not triggered, so you need to trigger it yourself. You can use events within datepicker to manage this:

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        altField: "#selected_day",
        altFormat: "DD",
        onSelect:function(){
            $('#selected_day').change()
        }
    });
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/c3u5B/12/

Not sure that you really need a change handler on the alt field and could just do the update from within datepicker

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `change` event doesn't fire on `selected_day` is because the value is changed programatically.

You need to trigger the `change` event on the `datepicker` element itself, like so:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  altField: "#selected_day",
  altFormat: "DD"
}).on('change', function() {
  var day = $('#selected_day').val();
  $('#result').text('Result: ' + day);
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3u5B/11/)

Comment: i was close! haha. Still learning :) Thanks so much, will accept it in 2 minutes